# mysql query showing wrong result

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a database table look like this

```
+======+===========+============+
|  ID  | user Name |user surname|
+======+===========+============+
| 100  |  name     |  surname   |
| 101  |  name     |  surname   |
| 102  |  name     |  surname   |
+===============================+
```

When i run this query which should show me no rows because there is no row with `101foo2` value :

> SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE ID = '101foo2'

I am getting a result with same ID without the `foo2` word

```
+======+===========+============+
|  ID  | user Name |user surname|
+======+===========+============+
| 101  |  name     |  surname   |
+===============================+
```

how it is showing the row with ID `101` if my query is `ID = '101foo2'`

Comment: Rule 1 if the datatype is a INT type don't use strings to fetch it.  MySQL trys auto converting `'101foo2'` into `101` if the column datatype is a INT.. That why your query results into getting that record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing types.  `ID` is an integer (or number).  You are comparing it to a string.  So, MySQL needs to decide what type to use for the comparison.  What types gets used?  Well, a string?  No.  A number.  The string is converted to a number, using the leading digits.  So, it becomes `101` and matches.

You should really only compare numbers to numbers, and strings to strings.  You could try to write the code as:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE ID = 101foo2
```

However, you would get an error.  Another possibility is to force the conversion to a string:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE CAST(ID as CHAR) = '101foo2'
```